# Entity Framework data updates in a multi-user environment with central database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, multi-user

Let me explain the title.

I'm using Entity Framework Code First in an application **(TestApp)**.
For debugging purposes the *TestApp* connects to an SQLExpress database (central database server).

To keep things simple here, the database contains one table "Products" and the TestApp shows all "Products" from the database in a datagrid and TestApp can add/delete a "Product" or modify the ProductName.

```
public class Product {
 public int ProductId { get; set; }
 public string ProductName { get; set; }
}

public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

I have for example 3 pc's where TestApp is installed and running (I'll call them Client_X). If I add a new "Product" via Client_1, than this is not directly visible in the TestApp on Client_2 and Client_3. Only when Client_2 and Client_3 fetch all the data again (manual refresh) than I see the newly added record.

What I want to know:
How can I be aware of changes in the database via EF Code First? 
How would Client_2 and Client_3 get their datagrid automatically updated because a new item was added or removed?

I'm not sure if it is asked too much but a simple sample project or simple code to demonstrate this would be useful.

*FYI: 
I'm fairly new to EF Code First.
(I'm using .NET 4.0 and EF Code First 4.3.1)*

Thanks in advance.

**Scheme:**

```
Client_3<
         \
          \
           \
            \
             \>
Client_1 <---> [Central Database] <----> Client_2
```

**Update/Edit:**

Ok, it is clear that the Entity Framework itself doesn't do any syncing between multiple clients.

**So i'll ask another question:**
I'm thinking of working the Client-Server way:

- A single server application which creates the database and uses the
  Entity Framework code first.
- Multiple clients that communicate with that single server
  application.

  What would now be the best way to make sure the clients use the same data and see eachothers updates/changes?
  (I would appreciate code samples.)

Comment: Found a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852564/entity-framework-underlying-data-in-database-change-notification

Comment: I want to do exactly the same thing, but with a web application. I have multiple web servers connecting to the same DB - Prasad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing you can use to notify clients using entity framework. You can write an overload for `SaveChanges`, or create extension method but as far as you do not have client->server architecture I can not imagine how you can achieve this.

If you use WCF as your gateway to the database, you could create duplex communication between your client and server and as new records are available clients would be notified using Callback Channel.

Another approach is to use MS SQL Service Broker [Overview (Service Broker)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166104%28v=sql.105%29)

Despite the fact, that there are many different ways to get desired result, none of them are related to entity framework as it is ORM nor a application framework or Communication framework for applications built with .NET.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the responsibility of EF, it is more down to your general application design. A relatively simple background or periodic polling process would solve your problem.

There are more considerations when dealing with multiple users, such as record locking and it may be an idea to do a little research into this side of things and come back if and when  you have a specific problem.

Comment: Polling doesn't look a good solution? Generating extra network traffic. Database has more work and if a user is scrolling in a datagrid his view would e.g; every minute be reset because of a refresh that loads all the data again.

Comment: @juFo They are only suggestions, you will need to do more general research into multi-user environments and figure the best overall solution yourself, it will be dependent on a lot of factors. My point is that it is not an EF problem.

Comment: So there is absolutely nothing in EF that tells you that your Context is outdated or that the database has newer data?

Comment: @juFo Look at it logically. You either need to check or be told that the non-local data has changed. I am unsure of a push notification, so pull (poll) is the only option left.

Comment: what about this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233770/AutoRefresh-Entity-Framework-data-using-SQL-Server ?

Comment: @juFo The link u provided seems to be really interesting I myself to give it a try and try to extend it using WCF

Comment: maybe this could also be useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716714.aspx